# Jmeter- how to get the dynamic session id value from response header

Tags: jmeter

[how to retrieve the corresponding dynamic session id in JMeter response header ]

X-Frame-Options: sample

JS-Client-Event-Session-Id: aaa-bbb

i tried from regular expression and json extractor but not able to retrieve the value.

[configured snippet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ssWk.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Without seeing your Regular Expression Configuration it's not possible to tell what's wrong and how it should be fixed
2. [HTTP Response Headers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) are being returned in form of a String, you won't be able to use JSON Extractor for parsing them.

Example Regular Expression Extractor configuration:

[image]

More information:

- [Apache JMeter: Regular Expressions](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/regular_expressions.html)
- [Using RegEx (Regular Expression Extractor) with JMeter](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207421325-Using-RegEx-Regular-Expression-Extractor-with-JMeter)

Comment: thanks for your helpful information Dmitri T this worked in retrieving in information.